# The dimension of the SU(2) matrix group

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let's take the matrix $R = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix}$.

Consider its transpose $R^\dagger = \begin{pmatrix} a^* & c^* \\ b^* & d^* \end{pmatrix}$.

Then $RR^\dagger =1$ implies that $|a|^2 + |c|^2 = 1, |b|^2 + |d|^2 = 1, ab^* + cd^* = 0,$ and $a^*b + c^*d = 0$.

The last two equations are equivalent to each other, so we have three complex equations.

If $a=a_0+ia_1, b=b_0+ib_1, c=c_0+ic_1,$ and $d=d_0+id_1$, then the above three complex equations lead to $a_0^2 + a_1^2+c_0^2+c_1^2=1, b_0^2 + b_1^2+d_0^2+d_1^2=1, a_{0}b_{0} + a_{1}b_{1} + c_{0}d_{0} + c_{1}d_{1} = 0,$ and $a_{0}b_{1} - a_{1}b_{0} + c_{1}d_{0} - c_{0}d_{1} = 0$.

Therefore, the three complex equations lead to four real equations (the first two equations have only real components, but the final equation has both real and complex components).

Therefore, the four real equations ensure that the number of real variables that parametrise the matrix $R$ drops from 8 to 4.

Now, let's consider the determinant equation $ad-bc=1$, which decomposes into $(a_{0}d_{0} - a_{1}d_{1} - b_{0}c_{0} + b_{1}c_{1}) + i(a_{1}d_{0} + a_{0}d_{1} - b_{1}c_{0} - b_{0}c_{1}) = 1,$ which decomposes into $a_{0}d_{0} - a_{1}d_{1} - b_{0}c_{0} + b_{1}c_{1} = 1,$ and $a_{1}d_{0} + a_{0}d_{1} - b_{1}c_{0} - b_{0}c_{1} = 0$.

Therefore, we have two real equations, so the number of parameters that characterise the matrix $R$ should now drop from 4 to 2. But several sources mention that the number of parameters drop from 4 to 3.

Can someone explain?

Comment: You need to worry about something like "linear independence"; not every equation here adds new information.

Comment: Well I think that the most convenient way to establish Lie group dimension is to move to tangent space in identity and find its dimension. All the equations becomes linear (e.g. condition on determinant after differentiating gives us that trace is equal to zero) and it is quite easy to find dimension then. One have to be really careful about these nonlinear equations!

Answer (score 1):

The explanation is that the determinant is already constrained to be on the unit circle.  We have $|\det(R)|^2 = \det(R)\overline{\det(R)} = \det(R)\det(R^\dagger) = \det(RR^\dagger) =\det(I) = 1$.

This means that the equation $a_0d_0 - a_1d_1 - b_0c_0 + b_1c_1 = 1$ implies $a_0d_1 + a_1d_0 - b_0c_1 - b_1c_0 = 0$, and the latter equation  implies $a_0d_0 - a_1d_1 - b_0c_0 + b_1c_1 = \pm 1$.  In other words, the set of five real equations has a nontrivial relation, which increases the dimension of the solution set.

Another way of looking at it is that the determinant gives a homomorphism $U(2) \to S^1$, and the first isomorphism theorem then guarantees that the dimension of the kernel $SU(2)$ is the dimension of the source minus the dimension of the image.